# How to determine open Outlook Contact from multiple open windows?

Tags: .net, outlook, contacts

How would I get a handle on an open Outlook contact, based on the active open contact window ("card") ?

So if I user had three Outlook contact windows open, when they alternate between them I can get a handle on the active Outlook.Contact object in the code-behind. I assume some event handler, but I haven't been able to find the right one.

I've been looking at the Outlook.Explorer:

```
            Object selObject = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];

            if (selObject is Outlook.ContactItem)...
```

but it always gives me the last contact opened, not the active contact among multiple ones open. So, each time a user alternates between open contact windows, I need to pull some properties of the active contact (name, phone numbers etc.) C# please.

Answer (score 0):

private void ContactCallMenu_OnCreate(object sender, ADXRibbonCreateMenuEventArgs e) 
{

```
IRibbonControl controlThatFiredEvent = e.Control; 
object context = controlThatFiredEvent.Context; 

if (context == null) return; 
if (context is Outlook.Explorer) 
{ 
    Outlook.Explorer explorer = context as Outlook.Explorer; 
    Outlook.Selection selection = null; 
    try 
    { 
        selection = explorer.Selection; 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
    } 
    if (selection != null) 
    { 
        if (selection.Count > 0) 
        { 
            object item = selection[1]; 
            if (item is Outlook.ContactItem) 
            { 
                Outlook.ContactItem contact1 = item as Outlook.ContactItem; 
                // process contact  
                MessageBox.Show("ContactCallMenu_OnCreate - contact1: " + contact1.Subject); 
            } 
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item); item = null; 
        } 
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selection); selection = null; 
    }  
} 
else if (context is Outlook.Inspector) 
{ 
    Outlook.Inspector inspector = context as Outlook.Inspector; 
    object item = inspector.CurrentItem; 
    if (item is Outlook.ContactItem) 
    { 
        Outlook.ContactItem contact2 = item as Outlook.ContactItem; 
        // process contact  
        MessageBox.Show("ContactCallMenu_OnCreate - contact2: " + contact2.Subject); 
    } 
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item); item = null;  
}
```